# Using Bootstrap/CSS to make pinterest style layout, posts will not fall right under the above post

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that I want to use bootstrap to create a pinterest type layout. It is for my own website, every time I want to add a new post, I would just add a new `<li></li>` to the unordered list. Now the only problem is the layout with varying heights causes issues. How could I resolve this but make it easier when I want to continue adding articles. By the way it should be chronological order so that my newest post would be the first one, etc.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKvwgK)

or the same code:

```
 ...
<body>

  <h1 class="text-center">Test Site</h1>
  <div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 1</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus. Mi volutpat eget mi viverra pharetra sed, curabitur leo possimus, non amet in eget phasellus, lorem quam, eget praesent semper tempor nam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 2</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 3</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 4</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus. Mi volutpat eget mi viverra pharetra sed, curabitur leo possimus, non amet in eget phasellus, lorem quam, eget praesent semper tempor nam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 5</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus. Mi volutpat eget mi viverra pharetra sed, curabitur leo possimus, non amet in eget phasellus, lorem quam, eget praesent semper tempor nam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 6</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
```

I want to have Box 5 & 6 to be right under Box 2 & 3. I don't want the big space between them. What would be the easiest way to make this work, and mobile friendly as well as?

Currently like this, but I want box 5 & 6 to follow underneath not have that extra space etc...:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know there are jQuery Plugins like Masonry, jQuery Waterfall to help close all those gaps.

if you try to create pinterest-like layout with bootstrap only, you can take a look at Bootstrap 4, http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns.

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/loveface/pen/QEYkGq)

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}

@media (max-width: 680px) {
    ul {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
  </style>

  <title>Test Site</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1 class="text-center">Test Site</h1>
  <div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li >
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 1</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus. Mi volutpat eget mi viverra pharetra sed, curabitur leo possimus, non amet in eget phasellus, lorem quam, eget praesent semper tempor nam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 2</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 3</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 4</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus. Mi volutpat eget mi viverra pharetra sed, curabitur leo possimus, non amet in eget phasellus, lorem quam, eget praesent semper tempor nam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 5</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus. Mi volutpat eget mi viverra pharetra sed, curabitur leo possimus, non amet in eget phasellus, lorem quam, eget praesent semper tempor nam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li >
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Box 6</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque lobortis mauris sem pellentesque parturient dolor, semper eu nulla, nunc aenean aenean amet donec, elementum sem repellat tempus ac, sint volutpat vestibulum. Tincidunt et et, justo tincidunt sed tellus mi eu, dolor sed lorem litora ante tincidunt. Pellentesque qui non error lectus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:flex; align-items:stretch;` to your ul element.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work properly for me. It stacks every box in a row. I need to have max 3 columns on a larger screen size, it will reduce to 2 and then 1 for extra small screen sizes.